# 429 error on my rails view but I don't know where I'm sending requests to Shopify's API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

It seems that I'm involuntarily sending requests to the Shopify API from my view:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Failed.  Response code = 429.  Response message = Too Many Requests.):

340:             myProducts.desc.push(description.substring(6, description.length-6) +' <br>'+
338: 
342:               '<p style=\"float:right;color:#c1c1c1;\"><a href=<%="https://#{shop_session.url}/products/#{product.handle}"%> target=\"_blank\">View in Shopify</a></p>');
343:             myProducts.img.push('<%= product.images.first.medium %>');
341:               '<p><i><%= product.price_range %> <%= shop_session.shop.currency %></i></p>'+
344:           }
app/views/home/index.html.erb:341:in `block in       _app_views_home_index_html_erb__4367043927235243173_45266480'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:328:in `each'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:328:in `each_with_index'
```

The code that produces the error is

```
<%  @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
      var escapedTitle = '<%= JSON.generate(raw(product.title), quirks_mode: true) %>';
      escapedTitle = escapedTitle.substring(6, escapedTitle.length-6);
      //console.log("COMPARE " + selectedProducts[i] + " WITH: " + escapedTitle);
      if (selectedProducts[i]== escapedTitle) {
        myProducts.title.push(selectedProducts[i]);

        //console.log("MATCH!");

        var description = '<%= JSON.generate(raw(product.body_html), quirks_mode: true) %>';

        myProducts.desc.push(description.substring(6, description.length-6) +' <br>'+
          '<p><i><%= product.price_range %> <%= shop_session.shop.currency %></i></p>'+
          '<p style=\"float:right;color:#c1c1c1;\"><a href=<%="https://#{shop_session.url}/products/#{product.handle}"%> target=\"_blank\">View in Shopify</a></p>');
        myProducts.img.push('<%= product.images.first.medium %>');
      }
    <% end %>
```

More specifically, the error is produced on line 328:

```
<%  @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
```

The controller for that view is sending the following request

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 250})
```

**Why is my view apparently sending more requests asking for products? How can I do it properly?**

The error is similar to [this one](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/why-would-i-get-a-429-error-on-a-view-when-i-m-not-reading-the-shopifyapi-181317) but in that case they were requesting for metafields, which are (or were) not included in the original request for products. But I'm directly working with the products, not with anything special.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was

```
myProducts.desc.push(description.substring(6, description.length-6) +' <br>'+
      '<p><i><%= product.price_range %> <%= shop_session.shop.currency %></i></p>'+
      '<p style=\"float:right;color:#c1c1c1;\"><a href=<%="https://#{shop_session.url}/products/#{product.handle}"%> target=\"_blank\">View in Shopify</a></p>');
```

More specifically, the part with

```
<%= shop_session.shop.currency %>
```

This was sending all the requests from my view. So, I added

```
@shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
```

to my controller and changed that code for

```
<%= @shop.currency %>
```

Problem solved.